# Appium inspector is not working for iOS 11

Tags: appium, ios11, xcode9, iphone7plus

I am getting below error when I try to launch Appium inspector:

ios-deploy[4198:260473] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000067: There was an internal API error. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
'.
[XCUITest] Error: Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id 9d16aca34aa6c5950e63689b526dbbfcebbe4b47 --bundle /var/folders/77/lc3w5ldx6cg8h6c9ykh00klmwydhgh/T/2017106-4081-lcrduf.4w6cpzxgvi/Payload/JiTriOS.app' exited with code 253'

I am using appium desktop 1.2.4,Xcode-9,iOS-11 and iPhone 7 Plus real device.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried with appium 1.2.6 as well but I am getting same error.

Comment: observed same. I am using Appium 1.8.1 [Desktop] and trying on iOS 11.2.5 iPhone. Any one resolve this issue?